# aticonfig: No supported adapters AMD Catalyst 15.7 Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, ati, fglrx

Have a fresh install of Ubuntu with no previous proprietary driver. Installed per AMD Installer notes using the GUI then added th fglrx-dev via dpkg.
Ran dpkg -l in home directory and all four show ii.

Then ran clinfo and got the following error "modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'fglrx': No such device
Error! Fail to load fglrx kernel module! Maybe you can switch to root user to load kernel module directly, this error listed three times,  Also listed device type as CPU not GPU.

When running aticonfig --initial get "No supported adapters detected. I see a file called aticonfig  in usr/bin. I also noticed there are six X11 folders nested in bin. Not sure what that's about.  I've fought this issue for two days. How hard can it be to install a stupid driver.

Answer (score -1):

I advice you to follow the instruction you could find on this page:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD#Installing_via_the_command_line

Check also to have enabled Backport and Partner source on APT and disable any internal graphics card if you have it.

I solved my problems like this.

Best